# Binding to LDAP with multiple certs. in ruby

Tags: ruby, ldap, openldap, netldap

I'm using https://github.com/ruby-ldap/ruby-net-ldap gem to connect/bind to LDAP

```
treebase = "ou=xxxxxx,dc=xxxxx,dc=xx"
credentials = {             
                :username => "myusername,ou=xxxxxx,dc=xxxxx,dc=xx",
                :password => "password"
}
encryption = {
                :method => :simple_tls,
                :tls_options => { :ca_path => "folder/Chain/pem_folder"}
}
# pem_folder = folder that contains multiple pem files

ldap = Net::LDAP.new :host => "hostname.example.com",
     :port => 636,
     :encryption => encryption,
     :base => treebase,
     :auth => credentials

ldap.bind
```

The above code results in 
`ruby-2.2.2/gems/net-ldap-0.12.1/lib/net/ldap/connection.rb:47:in open_connection': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (Net::LDAP::Error)`

I have a feeling it has something to do with the multiple certs but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was

1. Make sure you are connected to VPN if needed to be on the network
2. follow the [instruction here](http://mislav.net/2013/07/ruby-openssl/#SSL_CERT_FILE) specially the part about rehashing with `c_rehash`
3. my username was also missing `uid=` before which was causing failed binding
4. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539501/rails-ldap-login-using-net-ldap) also helped but I used [Figaro Gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) instead